# Optimizing string match in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

Currently, I have the following line, where I try to do a string match in a column of my pandas:

```
input_supplier = input_supplier[input_supplier['Category Level - 3'].str.contains(category, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

However, this operation takes a lot of time. The size of the pandas df is: `(8098977, 16)`.

Is there any way to optimize this particular operation?

Comment: Probably...reorganizing your data? I don't think the actual operation should be written differently, but if you find yourself doing a string search regularly, consider adding an extra column.

Answer (score 1):

Like Josh Friedlander said it will it should be a little faster adding a column and then filtering:

```
len(df3)

9599904

# Creating a column then filtering
start_time = time.time()
search = ['Emma','Ryan','Gerald','Billy','Helen']
df3['search'] = df3['First'].str.contains('|'.join(search))
new_df = df3[df3['search'] == True]
end_time = time.time()
print(f'Elapsed time was {(end_time - start_time)} seconds')

Elapsed time was 6.525546073913574 seconds
```

just doing a str.contains:

```
start_time = time.time()
search = ['Emma','Ryan','Gerald','Billy','Helen']
input_supplier = df3[df3['First'].str.contains('|'.join(search), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
end_time = time.time()
print(f'Elapsed time was {(end_time - start_time)} seconds')

Elapsed time was 11.464462518692017 seconds
```

It is about twice as fast to create a new column and filter on that than to filter on str.contains()

Comment: Thanks. This shaved close to 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Use fast numpy "where" and "isin" functions after converting search column values and category list values to lower case.  If the column and/or category list contain non-strings, convert to strings first.  Delete the column label in the last line if you want to see all columns from the original dataframe indexed to the search column results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

names = np.array(['Walter', 'Emma', 'Gus', 'Ryan', 'Skylar', 'Gerald',
                  'Saul', 'Billy', 'Jesse', 'Helen'] * 1000000)
input_supplier = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['Category Level - 3'])

len(input_supplier)
10000000

category = ['Emma', 'Ryan', 'Gerald', 'Billy', 'Helen']
```

Method 1 (note this method does not ignore case)

```
%%timeit
input_supplier['search'] = \
    input_supplier['Category Level - 3'].str.contains('|'.join(category))
df1 = input_supplier[input_supplier['search'] == True]

4.42 s ± 37.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Method 2

```
%%timeit
df2 = input_supplier[input_supplier['Category Level - 3'].str.contains(
    '|'.join(category), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]

5.45 s ± 25.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Numpy method ignoring case:

```
%%timeit
lcase_vals = [x.lower() for x in input_supplier['Category Level - 3']]
category_lcase = [x.lower() for x in category]
df3 = input_supplier.iloc[np.where(np.isin(lcase_vals, category_lcase))[0]]

2.02 s ± 31.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Numpy method if matching case:

```
%%timeit
col_vals = input_supplier['Category Level - 3'].values
df4 = input_supplier.iloc[np.where(np.isin(col_vals, category))[0]]

623 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```